# Show message in vim map

Tags: vim, vim-fugitive

I use [fugitive vim plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive).
with a map and [BufferIsEmpty function](https://gist.github.com/2949048), I close the diff buffer if this don't have changes.

I use this map

```
nn <silent><leader>g0 :w <bar> Gsplit! diff -U0 <bar>                                
    \ exec BufferIsEmpty() ? "q <bar> echomsg 'git: No changes'" : ''<CR>
```

but, I don't see the message `No changes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved with `redraw`

```
nn <silent><leader>g0 :w <bar> Gsplit! diff -U0 <bar>                                
    \ exec BufferIsEmpty() ? "q <bar> redraw <bar> echomsg 'git: No changes'" : ''<CR>
```